# ipad pro bootstrap (v4) navbar toggleable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, media-queries, navbar

iam using the bootstrap (v4) navbar element in my project. I set the navbar to toggle on `md` by adding the `navbar-toggleable-md` class.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-megamenu navbar-light">
```

My problem is, on an i pad pro the normal desktop navigation is shown. I want the mobile navigation (hamburger menu) to be shown on an ipad pro.

How can i achieve this? Do i have to modify the default bootstrap breakpoints?

Thanks

Comment: yes you can achieve it by overriding your media queries

Comment: https://medium.com/connect-the-dots/css-media-queries-for-ipad-pro-8cad10e17106